# Config nginx with nodejs, don't work with upload file POST request?

Tags: node.js, nginx, sails.js

I am trying to config nginx with nodejs ( sails.js framework ).
Nginx listen requests on port 80 and pass to 8080. All the request work fine ( all is post ), except the upload file post request.

Below is my nginx config file :

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off
        upstream node {
         # One failed response will take a server out of circulation for 20 seconds.
         server localhost:8080 fail_timeout=20s;
                 keepalive 512;
    }
        server {
         listen 80 default_server;
         listen 8191;
         listen 443 ssl;
         ssl    on;
         ssl_certificate    /home/ubuntu/APP/cert.pem;
         ssl_certificate_key     /home/ubuntu/APP/key.pem;
         server_name localhost;

         location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            # define buffers, necessary for proper communication to prevent 502s
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            }
        }
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uncommenting these lines?

```
#passenger_root /usr;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
```